# CakePHP Using Set::combine with localization

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying to use the localization features in cakephp. In app_model.php I have a method that gets the different payment methods.

```
function getDistinctFields($model, $field)
{
    $list = ClassRegistry::init($model)->find('all', array(
        'fields'=>array("DISTINCT $model.$field"), 
        'conditions' => array('not' => array("$model.$field" => null))
    ));
    debug($list);
    $translated = "{n}.$model.$field";
    $return = Set::combine($list, "{n}.$model.$field", __($translated, true));
    return $return;
}
```

The result of the debug($list) looks like this:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [InstantPaymentNotification] => Array
            (
                [payment_status] => Pending
            )
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [InstantPaymentNotification] => Array
            (
                [payment_status] => Completed
            )
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [InstantPaymentNotification] => Array
            (
                [payment_status] => Denied
            )
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [InstantPaymentNotification] => Array
            (
                [payment_status] => Refunded
            )
    )
```

The output of the method looks like this:

```
> Array (
>     [Pending] => Pending
>     [Completed] => Completed
>     [Denied] => Denied
>     [Refunded] => Refunded
>     [Reversed] => Reversed
>     [Canceled_Reversal] => Canceled_Reversal )
```

Nicer, but the value is not translated as it should be. I created the default.po file in the correct location and tested to see if it works on other pages. However, it seems it doesn't work with the Set class.

Comment: I rewrote the function without the just using a foreach and this works. If someone can still find how to do this with Set::combine I would like to hear it, thanks. 

function getDistinctFields($model, $field)
 {
     $list = ClassRegistry::init($model)->find('all', array(
         'fields'=>array("DISTINCT $model.$field"), 
         'conditions' => array('not' => array("$model.$field" => null))
     ));
     $nicer = Set::extract($list, "{n}.$model.$field");
     foreach($nicer as $nice){
         $translated[$nice] = __($nice, true);
     }
     return $translated;
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to manually localize within a `foreach` after calling `Set::combine`.  What you're currently doing is localizing the string "{n}.InstantPaymentNotification.payment_status", then sending that value into the `Set::combine` function.

You need to do something more like this:

```
function getDistinctFields($model, $field) {
    $list = ClassRegistry::init($model)->find('all', array(
        'fields'=>array("DISTINCT $model.$field"), 
        'conditions' => array('not' => array("$model.$field" => null))
    ));
    $list = Set::combine($list, "{n}.$model.$field", "{n}.$model.$field");
    foreach ($list as &$item) {
        $item = __($item, true);
    }
    return $list;
}
```